# Is there a reason to use $scope.$apply rather than $applyAsync?

Tags: angularjs

What would be a use case for calling $scope.$apply rather than $applyAsync? I'm probably missing something, but the latter just seems like a safer version of the former, so you can't get digest reentrancy.

Answer (score 9):

`$scope.$apply` will try to apply the given expression immediately, meaning that if a digest cycle is currently being run, you may end up getting an error/exception.

`$applyAsync` on the other hand will "schedule" the expression to be applied in about 10 milliseconds (as per the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)), so that you are able to queue more than one expression in the same digest cycle.

Comment: How frequently do you use either?  I've been working in Angular for a couple years and have only needed to force things on a handful of occasions.

Comment: @jKlaus I usually try to avoid using $apply. As a matter of fact, IMO, it's not a good practice to force a digest cycle and I always refactor my code so that angular handles the scope changes by itself.

Comment: If you're using an audio library to synchronize to sound, all the time!

Comment: @taxicala  That is my exact thought as well.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was whether there's ever a need to use $apply rather than $applyAsync. Should you always use the latter?